# What is the right way to arrange bottom button so that it doesn't leave a white area at the bottom of screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

For `UIToolbar`, if we use constraint

**toolbar bottom = safe area bottom**

[image]

It will work pretty well.

---

However, if I apply the same technique for `UIButton`

**button bottom = safe area bottom**

[image]

They will be an undesired white area at the bottom

---

Most suggestions are using

**button bottom = super view bottom**

[image]

However, if using this technique, I need to adjust the height of button with the following logic.

```
if iPhone SE {
    button height = 44
} else {
    button height = 44 + ???
}
```

---

May I know, what is the right way to arrange bottom button so that it doesn't leave a white area at the bottom of screen?

Comment: Put the button in the toolbar.

Comment: "However, if using this technique, I need to adjust the height of button with the following logic." Yes. So adjust it.  You've answered your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should constraint the button's bottom to the superview's bottom, not the safe area's bottom.

The logic to adjust the button's height is simple - you add a top constraint that is relative to the bottom of the safe area.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let buttonHeight = 36
    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -buttonHeight).isActive = true
}

override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
    super.viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()
    button.configuration!.contentInsets.bottom = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    
}
```

Note that I also set the content inset of the button, so that the button's title is not vertically centered. We want the title to move up a little so that it is in the safe area.

Comment: A slightly simpler alternative might be to forego the button's height constraint and set the button's topAnchor to be relative to the safeAreaGuide's bottomAnchor. No need for a separate constraint property. This also allows it to automatically adjust if the safe area size changes without any code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: @HangarRash Ah I didn't think of that. But I would need to adjust the content inset in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` anyway, right?

Comment: Yeah, that might be an issue. I'm still not sure why the OP doesn't just use the setup in their first picture - a toolbar with an appropriate bar button item.

Comment: @HangarRash One reason I can think of is they want the entire red area to be tappable.

Comment: Thank you. For the content insets adjusting, maybe `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange` is a better place? As, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` might be called multiple times.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Yes. I didn't know there was a specific method for that :)